# Postfix sender name

Tags: debian, postfix

I've got a problem with my postfix settings. I'd like to change the user name because when I use a command:

```
echo "Test" | mail -s "Test" my@email.com
```

It sends an email to me but the header "from" is like this:

```
root <mydomain@mydomain.com>
```

Mydomain is fine, I achieved it thanks by adding generic to my postfix settings. My question is: is it possible to change this "root" (or when I use `mail()`: www-data) to something else, eg. mydomain? So the full header "from" should be like this:

```
mydomain <mydomain@mydomain.com>
```

Is there anyone able to help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value in the Gecos in /etc/passwd by setting it to "mydomain".

By system command, run `chfn -f "mydomain" root`